# Create own library Android Java

Tags: java, android, methods, static, import

I wonder if it's possible I create my own library with my most frequently used methods ready to be called in my application.
Facilitating and speeding up my work.

It is possible to do this? How do? Someone gives an explanation of how to create and import? thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You just have to right click your Android Project in Eclipse, select on the left Android, and then you will have to check the `is Library` checkbox. To add this library to another project, you will just have to click `Add` on the same window in Eclipse.

You could also have a look at [Managing Projects from Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) especially at "Setting up a Project" section.

Answer (score 0):

Create a jar with all your frequently used files and move that jar to your project lib folder. It should work.